# php json_decode with data wrapped by [ ]

Tags: php, json

with true option, it works fine.

sorry and thanks guys.

=============================================

I encoded php array to json with this code

```
$rows = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);
    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

end decode with

```
$array = json_decode($server_output)
```

the $server_output is like this

```
[{"userid":"96679","userinfor":"xxxxxxxxx","userlocation":"CA"}]
[{"userid":"153795","userinfor":"xxxxxxxxx","userlocation":"CA"}]
[{"userid":"131878","userinfor":"xxxxxxxxx","userlocation":"CA"}]
```

but, $array is NULL :(

Thanks in advence,

Comment: Have you tried changing your array name? try adding json_decode($server_output, true);

Comment: You tried `$array = json_decode($server_output,true);` ?

Comment: How and where are you assigning a value to `$server_output`? Have you enabled error reporting (`ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`) and are there any reported errors? Also, the example you've given is not correct JSON. That's three separate arrays, not one JSON object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid json together:

```
[{"userid":"96679","userinfor":"xxxxxxxxx","userlocation":"CA"}]
[{"userid":"153795","userinfor":"xxxxxxxxx","userlocation":"CA"}]
[{"userid":"131878","userinfor":"xxxxxxxxx","userlocation":"CA"}]
```

While, this part is valid:

```
[{"userid":"96679","userinfor":"xxxxxxxxx","userlocation":"CA"}]
```

or any one of them separately

```
$json = '[{"userid":"96679","userinfor":"xxxxxxxxx","userlocation":"CA"}]';
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userid] => 96679
            [userinfor] => xxxxxxxxx
            [userlocation] => CA
        )

)
```

The valid format for all data is like this:

```
[
    {
        "userid": "96679",
        "userinfor": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "userlocation": "CA"
    },
    {
        "userid": "153795",
        "userinfor": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "userlocation": "CA"
    },
    {
        "userid": "131878",
        "userinfor": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "userlocation": "CA"
    }
]
```